# Total length of a tuple list in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on an exercise where I need to display the number of previous faculties in a joint faculty and the number of schools in the joint faculty.

I've successfully completed those steps and the problem I'm having is working out how I can print the:

4
5

together as '9' as a total instead of individually printing the lengths of the tuple separately.

I've been looking online everywhere for solutions but can't seem to find any solutions that work.

Below is my current code:

```
school1 = ('social sciences', 'business', 'law', 'philosophy')
school2 = ('maths', 'physics', 'computer science', 'chemistry', 
'biology')

previous = school1, school2
print('Number of previous faculties in the joint faculty: 
',len(previous))

print(len(school1))
print(len(school2))

for x in school1:
   print(x)

for y in school2:
   print(y)
```

Comment: `len(school1) + len(school2)` ? or `len(school1 + school2) # since both are tuples`

Comment: A simple addition of both tuple's lengths would solve the issue just as how @han solo suggested.

Comment: by adding them with a + symbol: print(len(school1) + len(school2))

Comment: You might want `previous = school1 + school2`, not `previous = school1, school2`.

Answer (score 2):

`len` returns an integer, so you can add them together

```
school1_len = len(school1) # 4
school2_len = len(school2) # 5
total = school1_len + school2_len
print(total)
```

You could also add the two tuples together, then take the length of the resulting tuple like `len(school1 + school2)`. Adding tuples concatenates them.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`reduce`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#reduce):

```
>>> l = (1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7, 8)
>>> reduce ((lambda x, y: x + len(y)), [0] + list (l))
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Just unpack them in one tuple as argument to len.

```
>>> school1 = ('social sciences', 'business', 'law', 'philosophy')
>>> school2 = ('maths', 'physics', 'computer science', 'chemistry', 
... 'biology')
>>> len((*school1,*school2))
9
```